# Laravel 5.2 use Illuminate\Http\Request Not working in subfolder Controller

Tags: laravel, request

I have make an AdminController in App\Http\Controllers folder with an index method and the Request it is working fine, i type in url bar http://localhost/brosta/public/index and i take the path "index" to my browser it's ok!

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->path();
        print_r($path);
        return view('index');
    }
```

But when i make the controller AdminController in a subfolder like App\Http\Controllers\Admin the requested path is not working. How can make it to work?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->path();
        print_r($path);
        return view('index');
    }
}
```

Ok! Now i have a different problem with the Request! With this way is working

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($request->path());
    }

}
```

But with this way is not working!

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $request = new Request;
        print_r($request->path());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line in your second controller.

`use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Since you are in a different namespace you need to add the correct namespace for the Controller class.

Comment: Please see again my new question if you understand something with that problem

Comment: Try resolving it out of the service container like this: `$request= $this->app->make('Request');`